# AWS EB Docker Amazon Linux 2 - Error occurred during build: Could not enable service awslogsd

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my app to a fresh ElasticBeanstalk environment and need to update the platform since the old one is no longer available.

Old: *Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.20.4*

New: *Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.5*

When I tried to deploy the app the build failed with this error:

```
Error occurred during build: Could not enable service awslogs (return code 1)
```

I saw that this service name has changed to `awslogsd` in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) and updated my code by referencing [this fix](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/62#issuecomment-468246736) for the same error.

However now when I deploy the build fails with this error:

```
Error occurred during build: Could not enable service awslogsd (return code 1)
```

**I don't see anyone else having issues with `awslogsd` - anyone know how I could debug this?**

Here's the services section of my `containerlogs.config` file in ebextensions folder:

```
services:
  sysvinit:
    awslogsd:
      enabled: "true"
      ensureRunning: "true"
      files:
        - "/etc/awslogs/config/containerlogs.conf"
```

I also have a `auditlogs.config` file with:

```
services:
  sysvinit:
    awslogsd:
      enabled: "true"
      ensureRunning: "true"
      files:
        - "/etc/awslogs/config/auditlogs.conf"
```